# Is there a way to push CI builds automatically to @Release in Aure DevOps Nuget push task?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Using Azure DevOps new yaml pipelines, I am finding it behaves differently than in the past.  I am pushing to a local Nuget feed.

My current push task is working fine:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '$(localGuid)'
```

but this is then only visible in the @Local feed, is there any way to automatically have this pushed to @Release for specified builds?
[image: devops]

Comment: `but this is then only visible in the @Local feed, is there any way to automatically have this pushed to @Release for specified builds?` Can you share some details about @Local @Release, I'm not very clear about these two points, what does @Release mean? @Release refers to the feed name, release pipeline or nuget package with release version ?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to push CI builds automatically to @Release in Aure DevOps Nuget push task?

I am afraid there is no such way to push CI builds automatically to `@Release` in Aure DevOps `Nuget push task`.

As workaround, we could use the REST API [NuGet - Update Package Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/update%20package%20versions?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

```
POST https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/nuget/packagesbatch?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Request body:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewId": "{viewId}"
  },
  "operation": 0,
  "packages": [{
    "id": "{packageName}",
    "version": "{packageVersion}",
    "protocolType": "{NuGet|Npm}"
  }]
}
```

or use curl:

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PATCH --user your_user:your_pass \
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/your_org/_apis/packaging/feeds/you_feed_id/upack/packages/apim/versions/you_pack_version?api-version=5.0-preview.1 \
--data '{"views": {"op": "add", "path": "/views/-", "value": "Prerelease"}}'
```

Besides, there is an extension [Promote package to Release View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.vsts-promotepackage-task) to promote a package to a Release View Please.

You could check the [similar thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2333) for some more details.

Hope this helps.